# NoClassDefFoundError-very strange behaiour

Tags: java, exception

While learning exceptions i tried the following steps and found a very strange behavior. Please find the steps below.

- Created a Public Class `A`
- Create a class `B`
- Compiled `A` and `B`
- Deleted the class `B` before running `A`

After doing above steps program runs absolutely fine and throws `NoClassDefFoundError` ,Now strange thing is **when i declare the reference variable inside the `try` block and run the program again it throws an uncaught `NoClassDefFoundError`**

```
public class A{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           B m ;//Caught is getting printed if declare above try-catch()
        try {
            B m = new B();//Here Uncaught exception is throws
        } catch (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError ex) {
            System.out.println("Caught!");
        }
    }
}

class B{

}
```

I really don't have any idea why this is happening please help me understand this

Comment: please add both stacktraces

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java

Comment: Just declaring a reference to `B` should not throw the exception

Comment: No it won't but declaring outside try and use it inside catch will.

Comment: @ShowStopper - Yes, where you declare it doesn't really matter. You need to ensure that the JVM tries to load the class

Comment: Thanks got your answer, very well explained...:)

Comment: @ShowStopper - Use the `Java -v` option to see if the class `B` is loaded or not :) . Also, note that there is a difference between class loading and class initialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are deleting the class file of `A` after `B` has compiled and generated bytecode. So, code of `B` still references `A` and when your `A` starts running, the JVM will try to load and initialize `B` when the object is being created and since it cannot find the class in the class path of `A`, it throws NoClassDefinitionFoundException.

In your fist case you just declare a reference to `B`, the JVM will NOT try to load your class unless it really needs it, so you wont get any exception.